# Can't understand why I'm out of bonds with this IndexError: index 10000 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 10000

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop, index-error

Unfortunately I know VERY WELL this index error which simply says I'm out of bounds.
But I cannot understand how this is the case in my current code. 
I did everything to not be out of bounds. 
If someone knows what I should change to fix this, please help.

```
import numpy as np 
import numpy.random as npr

j=0
T=10
M=10000
N=200
h=T/N
sigma=np.linspace(0.1,0.6,num=5)
X=np.ones(shape=(5*M,N)) 
X[:,0]=0.5  # X0=0.5
Z=npr.randn(M,N)    
for S in range(1,6):  
    s=sigma[S-1]
    while j<=(S*M-1): **# PROBLEM IS HERE, it fills X array rows 0-9999 and no more!** 
        for i in range(0,N-1): 
            X[j,i+1]=X[j,i]+X[j,i]*(1-X[j,i])*h+s*Z[j,i]*np.sqrt(h)        
        j+=1 
**# supposed to take another S and keep going**
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like Z array doesn't have the right dimension. It's MxN whereas X is 5MxN